# Did the early church bow down to and venerate images/statues?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, veneration, statues

Catholic and Orthodox Christians believe in the veneration of images and states and bow down to them in order to show them veneration, but did the Early Church Fathers believe in venerating images and bow down to them in order to show respect and honour, but did the Early Church Fathers believe and practice bowing to and venerating images/statues?

Comment: The real problem with this particular question is that the Early Church was under persecution during the first four centuries and churches rarely existed in the sense that we know them now. Early Christians often met in homes or Catacombs.

Comment: Are you really asking about the apostolic fathers? How early is “early church”.  The first Christian’s were reformed Jews  it is a sure bet that they did not venerate any images or statues

Comment: There is an issue with the premise of this question. Catholic/Orthodox Christians do not venerate images/statues, they venerate people, specifically Saints. They often have images/statues as sacramentals but the veneration is toward a person not an object. The church has always rejected the veneration of objects as a form of idolatry.